# Umbraco YSOD - Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql, umbraco

When logging into the Umbraco office, I have seen the following error. The error is hard to reproduce and occurs intermittently.

```
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error only happens on local development environments, whilst running multiple websites on a single hostname. E.g. localhost

This is the default configuration for Visual Studio and IIS Express.

As such, when working on 3 projects you would have:

localhost:10000
localhost:20000
localhost:30000

Same host, different ports.

Because of this each web application can see the others cookies.

**To resolve the issue, clear the cookies in the browser.**

This is worth considering for any website running on localhost.

Comment: I get this constantly - your solution is the perfect answer and I use the Web Developer Extension for Chrome to quickly and easily kill all cookies on the current domain only.